# Eventbrite API search_event methods no return data start from yesterday

Tags: eventbrite

I just wondering is there any change for the Eventbrite API search_event Methods?

Because it didn't return any data start from yesterday.

there is no problem before. here is the example url call back

https://www.eventbrite.com/json/event_search?app_key=#####&within=1&latitude=45.5&longitude=-73.58&max=100

Please help!

Thank you and have a nice day